# Dialogflow Fulfillment responses doesnt seems to work with richresponses(Basic Card) and OutputContext or Follow-up Event

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to setup a bot using dialogflow/webhook. my webhook returns the response for basic text message along with contextoutputs(esp. I am interested in parameters passed from webhooks). This works. But when i use the Basic card response of V2 along with outputcontext, Actions-on-google simulator says, "My test app isn't responding right now. Try again soon." But this works, if i remove outputcontext from the response. Please help

Steps Worked:
1. DialogFlow Testing 
   Basic Message (FulfillmentText) and contextoutput works fine
   Card and contextOutput - not working
   Card and followupEvent - Works
2. Actions on Google
   Basic Message (FulfillmentText) and contextoutput works fine
   Card and contextOutput - not working
   Card and followupEvent - not working
Attached the response

````
{
    "payload": {
      "google": {
        "expectUserResponse": true,
        "richResponse": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "This is sample Response"
              }
            },
            {
              "basicCard": {
                "title": "testbot",
                "formattedText": "This is sample  Response",
                "image": {
                  "url": "example.com/image.png",
                  "accessibilityText": "samplebot"
                },
                "buttons": [
                  {
                    "title": "example",
                    "openUrlAction": {
                      "url": "http://example.com"
                    }
                  }
                ]

              }
            }
          ]
        }

      }
    },
    "outputContexts": [{
              "name": "projects/<projectid>/agent/sessions/<sessionid>/contexts/<contextname>", 
              "lifespanCount": 1, 
              "parameters": {
                "param1": "123",
                "param2": "456"
              }
        }]

  }```
````

Comment: Hi! Can you please edit this question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem? Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") should include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've used the sample code in your action. However, unless you changed the url fields, your action can not find the imageUrl and openUrlAction.

If you change url fields with actual(not "http://example.com") links, your app will respond properly.

Also make sure you've added necessary classes.

e.g.

`const { dialogflow, BasicCard, Image, Button } = require('actions-on-google');`